# Swift: Async callback in command line utility

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, swift, runloop

I'm trying to fetch data from a website via a command line utility in swift. I'm using `NSURLConnection` for this. Like so:

```
private let queue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url), queue: queue) { (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        println("Hello")
}
```

But the application stops running before the callback is called. How do I keep the application running so it won't exit early? I found `CFRunLoop()` and have added that in my main file. Now the application doesn't terminate. But I still don't get a response.

The same project in a playground with `XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely` does work however. So the problem does not lie in the NSURLConnection code.

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/a/25126900/1187415 ?

Comment: private let queue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue() - added to example.

Comment: I have tried it with dispatch_main() and with NSRunLoop as in the referenced answer, and that worked for me.

Comment: The comment or Martin R contains the solution. Adding [dispatch_main()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_main.3.html) to the end of my main function. `Programs must call dispatch_main() at the end of main() in order to process blocks submitted to the
     main queue.`