# Using NSURLSession from a Swift command line program

Tags: macos, swift, nsurlsession, nsrunloop

I'm trying to test a little proof-of-concept command line app prior to integrating it into a larger app. What I'm trying to do is download some data using NSURLSession using [this example](https://medium.com/swift-programming/learn-nsurlsession-using-swift-ebd80205f87c). However it appears that if I use the examples given in a simple OS X command line app then the app exits prior to the data being retrieved.

How can I download data from a stand-alone command line app using NSURLSession? What I've read about is using [NSRunLoop](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/index.html) however I've not yet found a clear example in Swift so if NSRunLoop is actually the way to go then any examples would be appreciated.

Any other strategies for downloading data from a URL for a Swift command line app is also welcome (infinite while loop?).

Comment: Try adding `NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().run()` at the end of your file...

Comment: Thanks, that works. So, to confirm, that just runs until the program is terminated externally? You can add that as an answer and any extra info would be appreciated. Such as a) how to exit programmatically b) and a little bit of background info on why it's better than an infinite while loop.

Comment: yes--that will just run forever.

Comment: I added an answer, I will add some detail

Comment: ok--looks like you don't need the runloop after all. you can use GCD semaphores.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use a semaphore to block the current thread and wait for your URL session to finish.

Create the semaphore, kick off your URL session, then wait on the semaphore. From your URL session completion callback, signal the semaphore.

You could use a global flag (declare a volatile boolean variable) and poll that from a while loop, but that is less optimal. For one thing, you're burning CPU cycles unnecessarily.

Here's a quick example I did using a playground:

```
import Foundation

var sema = DispatchSemaphore( value: 0 )

class Delegate : NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate
{
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data)
    {
        print("got data \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8 ) ?? "<empty>")");
        sema.signal()
    }
}

let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: Delegate(), delegateQueue: nil )

guard let url = URL( string:"http://apple.com" ) else { fatalError("Could not create URL object") }

session.dataTask( with: url ).resume()    

sema.wait()
```

Comment: This is a really good solution. Really need a framework around this idea to keep track of all the semaphores you would create as necessary.

Comment: Probably once Swift gets native support for "async" type features, that won't be necessary anymore.

Comment: If you want a high-level solution, check out `NSOperationQueue` and `NSBlockOperation`

Comment: @nielsbot - If you have time/inclination - do you mind updating that solution for Swift 3?

Comment: Hi--I just pasted this into a Swift 3 Playground. Does it not work for you?

Comment: So the semaphore wait doesn't burn cpu?

Comment: @nielsbot also, does nsrunloop burn ? it seems more efficient than using while loops. I wonder what it does under the hood...

Comment: It does not burn cycles. It sleeps the main thread until the kernel wakes it up to handle an event: such as a timer firing or a key being pressed.

Comment: If you have nested net calls, make sure to signal on every happy path and fail path branch.

Comment: Everyone should check out @thiagoh's simpler answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41726693/210171

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```
let sema = DispatchSemaphore( value: 0)

let url = URL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/Cat_November_2010-1a.jpg")!;

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
  print("after image is downloaded");
  sema.signal(); // signals the process to continue
};

task.resume();
sema.wait(); // sets the process to wait
```

Answer (score 7):

For proof of concept(s) or tryouts/testing purposes, you can simplify asynchronous complexity by **hard coding** some timeout period until your stuff finishes. (see notes below)

**SWIFT 5**

```swift
    //...your magic here
    // add a little iness to make it fun at least...
    RunLoop.main.run(until: Date() + 0x10)  //oh boi, default init && hex craze 
    // yeah, 16 seconds timeout

    // or even worse (!)
    RunLoop.main.run(until: .distantFuture)
```

**SWIFT 3 or earlier**

```swift
    //...your stuff here
    RunLoop.main.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15))  //will execute things on main loop for 15 seconds
```

**NOTES** :

1. DO NOT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION
2. respect the first rule

This is very **quick and dirty** way to overcome serious concerns of parallelism. Explore better and more complex solutions described in other answers of this question.

Comment: can `sleep(15)` do the same trick? (re-reply from http://stackoverflow.com/a/40870288/1135503)

Comment: @KentLiau : do you assume C sleep() function ? If so, you need to import Darwin module, but be mindful of the underlaying OS you're running code on.