# How do i use timer function properly

Tags: swift, timer

I have been trying to make an easy incremental game, just to learn, and i couldnt figure out how to use timer to give the user "coins" every second. This question might have been asked a lot but all the solutions tutorials etc i read were too hard/outdated/not valid for my case.

edit: current code

```
import Foundation
import Darwin
//vars
var copperCoins = 0
var copperGrowth = 1

//intro
print("Simple incremental game!")

print("Copper coins: \(copperCoins)")
//while runs
while true
{
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
        copperCoins += copperGrowth
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Maybe some code you've already written?

Comment: @lancylot2004 done. it isnt very good but is understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Darwin` is not needed, and the `while` loop is not needed either

Create a strong reference to the timer to be able to modify it for example to stop and recreate the timer.

This runs 20 times and then invalidates the timer.

```
import Foundation

var copperCoins = 0
var copperGrowth = 1

//intro
print("Simple incremental game!")

print("Copper coins: \(copperCoins)")
var timer: Timer?

timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
    copperCoins += copperGrowth
    print(copperCoins)
    if copperCoins >= 20 { timer.invalidate() }
}
```

Comment: while running this the copper coins dont get modified as expected.
my console:
Simple incremental game!
Copper coins: 0
Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944011/how-to-prevent-a-command-line-tool-from-exiting-before-asynchronous-operation-co is probably helpful

Comment: To run the code in a "Terminal" app you need a runloop or use Swift Concurrency.

Comment: @vadian. thanks. But the answer you provided doesnt modify the copper coin value.

Comment: It does, please try the code in a Playground.

Comment: @vadian im not using a playground cuz of readLine(), but i realised i have to do timer.fire(). thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

First, you've got a forever-loop which creates loads of timers but never uses them - this might not be good. You only need to create it once, then use it.

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
    copperCoins += copperGrowth
    print(copperCoins)
}
```

Second, a timer needs to be started: `timer.fire()`, which should go outside.

But the last one - timers are usually used in apps to... time stuff. if you're doing this in a playground or just one script, the code will probably fire the timer once and just stop, since it's finished executing.

This I'm not sure but I think you can use a loop at the end to keep the code going:

```
while true {
    if copperCoins > 100 { break }
}
```

At the end, which means your code will only stop once `copperCoins` reaches 100. Probably not the best way to test timers in playground, but in any case this might be a problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: while running this the copper coins dont get modified as expected. my console: Simple incremental game! Copper coins: 0 Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: Don't forget the `timer.fre()` - exit code 0 usually means programme exited with no issues (as far as the computer can tell).