# Result of asynchronous function doesn't print when called in command line app

Tags: swift, command-line

I want to print the current stock price of Apple in the console.
The code runs, but it does not print anything. Can someone help me solve this?
(I have blurred out my API key)

```
import Foundation

func getStockPrice(symbol: String) {
    let apiKey = "****************"
    let symbol = "AAPL"
    let urlString = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=\(symbol)&apikey=\(apiKey)"
    
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error collecting data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        guard let data = data else {
            print("No data received")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
            if let globalQuote = json?["Global Quote"] as? [String: Any],
               let price = globalQuote["05. price"] as? String {
                print("Stock price for \(symbol): \(price)")
            } else {
                print("Could not get stock price")
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error with JSON-data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Where did you put that code? In Playgrounds? Where is the call of `getStockPrice()`?

Comment: I put it in Xcode Command Line Tool. I´ve tried to call with: ```getStockPrice(symbol: "AAPL")```
Both over and under the func

Comment: The command line app probably exits long before the asynchronous call to get the data has a chance to complete.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944011/how-to-prevent-a-command-line-tool-from-exiting-before-asynchronous-operation-co

Comment: Thanks, it worked when the code was put in playground, also when i called the function. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: I tried this code in playground and it worked with the changes suggested above. But when I tried to create an app in Xcode 15.1 I get this error nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array [C1.1.1 proxy pac] Evaluation error: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003. Looking for suggesting I fund that It is probably an ATS setting but I can't see how to do this as the plist file in the new IOS version is now under INFO - so stuck