# Swift NSURLSession Request to local server - no data sent or received

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

I'm attempting to write a simple API client in Swift 2.2 using `NSURLSession` for a server I'm running locally at port 3000. The server just serves up a static string of JSON.

This works fine:

```
$ curl http://localhost:3000
{"data":"value"}
```

My Swift code to hit the API is:

```
// api_client.swift

let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000/api")

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
    print("The response was:")
    print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}

print("Running the request...")
task.resume()
```

I'm attempting to run it from the command line

```
$ swift api_client.swift
Running the request...
```

But that's all that happens. I don't see the "The response was" line printed, or the response from the server. When I check the server logs it shows no request came in at all.

What am I doing wrong? I'm very new to Swift and am having trouble figuring this out.  I'm on Swift 2.2 and XCode 7.3

Comment: My guess is that this method is async and the runtime is reaching the end of your code before the method finishes executing so the completion is never called.

Comment: @pbush25 so how could I test this is the case and then fix it? What's a better way to run code like this? I don't want to go make a full-blow iOS app yet (although that's eventually the goal) just to get this piece working.

Comment: If you run this code *from the command line* it won't work because in this case your app has no runloop. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702387/using-nsurlsession-from-a-swift-command-line-program

Comment: awesome! thank you! I actually managed to get a response from the server just by wrapping my request in `while true { task.resume() }`. Not very elegant but at least I know the request was made.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to pbush25 I figured out that my request wasn't executing because the runtime reached the end of the file before the async request kicked off.

[Another user with this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702387/) solved it using semaphores, but a quick and dirty way to prove this was the problem was by adding `sleep(1)` at the bottom of the code.  If I do this, I see request in the logs and the data returned!

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on what pbush25 said. Can you try to create a callback in your code?

```
func GET(path : String, callback: (result: NSData?, response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()  
    let url = NSURL(string: path)  
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!){  
        (data, response, error) -> Void in  
            if (error != nil) {
                // return the NSData as nil (since you have an error)
                callback(result: nil, response: response as? NSHTTPURLResponse, error: error!)
            } else {
                // return the NSData
                callback(result: data, response: response as? NSHTTPURLResponse, error: nil)
            }
        }  
    task.resume()  
}
```

And then calling your function with:

```
GET("http://localhost:3000/api") {
    (data, response, error) -> Void in 
    print(data)
}
```

Comment: I had to edit the code for a few mistakes, but once I did and ran it, again, nothing happened at all. No request in my server logs.