# iOS Simulator not sending http requests to localhost mac running tomcat webservice

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

> Important information, I am running all this under a TestCase.

My URL is `http://my-MacBook-Pro.local:8080/myapi/v2/Driver/getDriver?domain=123&driver=125&key=9808098`

If I paste this URL on `Safari` running on the same `iPhone Simulator`. It responds with the JSON. I noticed my catalina.out reported this request.

I have enabled `Allow HTTP Services` on `Settings->Developer`.

This is the code snippet

```
print("fullurl ->"+urlComponents.url!.absoluteString)

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlComponents.url!, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print("error")
        }else{
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
                print (json)

            }catch let error as NSError{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }).resume()
```

**EDIT**

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http/32560433#32560433)
Added the following to `info.plist`, still my http request did not get thru to my `localhost` mac running tomcat on `port 8080`

```
<dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>My-MacBook-Pro.local</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

**EDIT**

Tried even with these settings in `info.plist`. No impact. Did a `Clean`, yet no impact.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Something wrong with my code I guess.

Comment: do you have some errors in the console log? if yes, please paste here

Comment: No errors on console log.

Comment: You have a bunch of `print` statements in your code. Can you share the output from those statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running network calls under a test case, needs the framework of `XCTestExpectation`.

Test case does not wait for `async` `completionHandlers` to be called. Unfortunately `XCTestExpectation` framework is not design friendly. We should be able to integrate test cases without having to change our class structure.

Lets track the responses to this on the [Apple Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/213526)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the appropriate flag in the info.plist file in the same way you do for asking to track user locations or to access the photo library and camera. Apple blocks, by default, requests to insecure web calls, i.e. http.

You can look up how to set individual exceptions or set the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to true to allow `ALL` insecure calls. Naturally this is considered the easier but less safe option.

Comment: Did not work as yet. I added permissions to info.plist.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http

Comment: I'll look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053593/swift-3-urlsession-datatask-completionhandler-not-called tomorrow.

Comment: Adding `NSALLOWSArbitaryLoads` did not work, I still cannot see tomcat catalina.out logs from this Xcode test case

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your AppDelegate:

```
setenv("CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS", "3", 1);
```

Like described here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1887/_index.html

This should log out something like "The network log file is in file: x" and you can grep the file for your URL and check if there are any logged errors there that did not show up in your app. This is a very good way of debugging ATS or other network connectivity problems, as it is very verbose.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for. So you are saying that the async http response will continue to run and log into a network log file for offline analysis. Great!! I added this line to AppDelegate, but I dont know where to find the network log file. All I can see is the "Test session log"

Comment: I think I should find that file in CrashReporter folder under `Logs`. I am unable to find that folder.

Comment: It should be one of the first things it logs to the console when you set it.

Comment: I was running it as a test case, not as a app. Now when I run it as an app everything starts to work.

Comment: Please post the whole method in which this is run