# Delegate functions are not called - NSURLConnection

Tags: macos, swift, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I'm new to swift coding, so most of my code is "this is how I found it on the internet" status.

I'm trying to send a HTTP GET request and then work with it. I'm using `NSURLConnection` for this. I have 2 swift files in my Xcode project (it is a swift console project, not playground), one is main one and 2nd contains my class I would like to use for delegation:

```
import Foundation

class Remote: NSObject, NSURLConnectionDelegate {

    var data = NSMutableData()

    func connect() {
        var url =  NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

        NSLog("Is%@ main thread", NSThread.isMainThread() ? "" : " NOT");
        var conn = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)
        conn?.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
        conn?.start()

        sleep(2)
    }


    func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
        println("didReceiveResponse")
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData conData: NSData!) {
        println("didReceiveData")
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        println("DidFinishLoading")
    }

    deinit {
        println("deiniting")
    }

}
```

Here is my main swift code:

```
import Foundation

var xxx = Remote()
xxx.connect()

sleep(10)

sleep(2)
```

When I set breakpoints on each `println` in delegate functions, they are never hit. Execution is done from main thread according to `NSLog` output.

In debugger I can see that data are sent and received over the network, but I never get any output. I've seen many similar questions here but nothing helped me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that a command-line program? Then you have to add a runloop, see for example [CFRunLoop in Swift Command Line Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126471/cfrunloop-in-swift-command-line-program).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Martin R** suggested I added correct NSRunLoop into my code right after starting *NSURLConnection*:

```
self.shouldKeepRunning = true
let theRL = NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop()

while self.shouldKeepRunning && theRL.runMode(NSDefaultRunLoopMode, beforeDate: NSDate(timeInterval: 1.0, sinceDate: NSDate())) { }
```

*shouldKeepRunning* is bool variable defined in my class and it set to false in delegate function *connectionDidFinishLoading*, so