# URLSession in command line tool: control multiple tasks and convert HTML to text

Tags: swift, macos, html-parsing, nsurlsession, swift3

In my project for OS X Command Line Tool using Swift 3.0 (Beta 2) I need to convert HTML data to String from multiple URLs. There is a problem in use of such function with many background tasks (it's not working except the main thread, so maybe there is more elegant way to control completion of all tasks and read HTML data in such tool with or without parsers that I need for Swift 3 and Mac OS X (Linux in the near future)):

```
func html2text (html: String, usedEncoding: String.Encoding) -> String {

    let data = html.data(using: usedEncoding)!

    if let htmlString = AttributedString(html: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: usedEncoding.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)?.string {
        return htmlString
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
```

So I read data first into an Array, waiting when all DataTasks finished and then converting it in the main thread. Also using global variable (Set of urls) to control completion of each task:

```
import Foundation
import WebKit

var urlArr = [String]()
var urlSet = Set<String>()
var htmlTup : [(url : String, html : String, encoding : String.Encoding)] = []

let session = URLSession.shared
```

For-in loop with multiple URLSession DataTasks

```
    for myurl in urlArr {
        if urlSet.insert(myurl).inserted {
            print ("Loading \(myurl)...")

            let inputURL = URL(string: myurl)!
            let task = session.dataTask(with: inputURL, completionHandler: {mydata, response, error in
```

Read Encoding from HTML First

```
           var usedEncoding =  String.Encoding.utf8
           if let encodingName = response!.textEncodingName {

                    let encoding = CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding(encodingName)
                    if encoding != kCFStringEncodingInvalidId {                            
                        usedEncoding = String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(encoding))                            
                    }
                }
```

Do some work with HTML String and read data into an Array

```
if let myString = String(data: mydata!, encoding: usedEncoding) {                  
                htmlTup += [(url: myurl,html: myString, encoding: usedEncoding)]
                }
                // The end of task removing URL from Set
                urlSet.remove(myurl)                    
            })
            //Run Task
            task.resume()  
        }
    } 
}
```

Waiting for tasks to complete and convert HTML to text

```
while !urlSet.isEmpty {
// Do nothing
}

for (url,html,encoding) in htmlTup {
    print ("Writing data from \(url)...")    
    print (html2text(html: html, usedEncoding: encoding))
}
```

**Update 1:** RunLoop in the main thread from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126471/cfrunloop-in-swift-command-line-program)
Such code to check when each task finished:

```
var taskArr = [Bool]()
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
}
                            taskArr.removeLast()
                        }
                        taskArr.append(true)
                        task.resume()

// Waiting for tasks to complete
            let theRL = RunLoop.current
            while !taskArr.isEmpty && theRL.run(mode: .defaultRunLoopMode, before: .distantFuture) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just spin in a busy loop waiting for results, because you're blocking the main run loop/thread/dispatch queue by doing that.

Instead, return at that point, thus allowing the main run loop to run.  Then, in your completion handler, check to see if you've gotten all the responses you're expecting, and if so, do the stuff that you currently have after that busy wait while loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I need more understanding of how things work